# Make images darker from bottom?

Tags: css, image, background, tailwind-css, background-image

Can anyone guide how to make image darker from bottom? I want to design the following box via tailwind css.[image: Sample design]

Currently, I tried by adding image as a normal div element(not background image) and then added the text div as absolutely positioned but I realise that the image should be in background and text should added as static div. Can you please suggest how to make the image darker as above attached picture?

Comment: Please share examples, codes and what did you try

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options for making an overlay over an image.

For a `background-image` property, you can define a gradient before the image URL. E.g.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .6), transparent 35%), url('image.jpg');
```

For an `<img>` tag, you can use a pseudo-element to create an overlay.

Here's one of many approaches you can take. E.g.

```
<head>
  <style>
    .overlay {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .overlay img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .overlay::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .6), transparent 35%);
      poionter-events: none;
    }
    
    .overlay-content {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 2;
      padding: 1em;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="overlay">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/500/300" alt="An image" />
    <div class="overlay-content">
      <p>Some text<p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```